# aggregate column values into list ignoring the None values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
ID col1 col2
1  val1 None
1  val2 val3
```

And I want to group by ID and aggregate col1 and col2 using list so I am doing:

```
df = df.groupby('ID') \
            .agg({'col1': lambda x: list(x),
                  'col2': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
```

and the output is:

```
ID col1          col2
1  [val1, val2]  [None, val3]
```

But what I need to do is to ignore the None value when aggregating and get the following output:

```
    ID col1          col2
    1  [val1, val2]  [val3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply modify your groupby like this:

```
df = df.groupby('ID') \
            .agg({'col1': lambda x: list(x[x.notna()]),
                  'col2': lambda x: list(x[x.notna()])}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is `None` object (i.e. it is not string `'None'`), you may take advantage of `filter` with `None`

```
df_out = df.groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: list(filter(None, x)))

Out[797]:
            col1    col2
ID
1   [val1, val2]  [val3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `groupby` and `stack`/`unstack`:

```
(df.set_index('ID')
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=[0,1])
   .agg(list)
   .unstack()
   .reset_index())

    ID     col1       col2
0   1  [val1, val2]  [val3]
```

---

*Note*: This takes advantage of the fact that missing values are dropped by default when using `stack`